# Site search is not filtering results based on Language

Tags: lucene, sitecore

**For e.g.** There is an item with name "ABC" in English and its corresponding versions in Japanese, Korean and Chinese(with translated content).
 If search keyword is "ABC" , then in Korean 0 results are expected but instead of that its returning Korean version even though there are no words "ABC" expect the item name.

Below is the code for filtering:

```csharp
query = query.Filter(item => item.Language == Sitecore.Context.Language.Name);
```

Fetching results:

```csharp
 query = query.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(word) || x.Content.Contains(word));
```

Please provide your inputs for this issue.

Sitecore Version :8.0

Search engine : Lucene

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `where` clause includes `|| x.Content.Contains(word))`

The `Content`property of the `SearchResultItem` class is a concatenation of all tokenized fields, including the item name. So for this reason I think the behaviour is correct.

I recommend using the specific fields you want search on rather than using `Content`.

You may have a field named `"content"` in your item. If that's the case then you can avoid the conflict of property names in your POCO by simply mapping it to a different property as follows:

```csharp
[IndexField("content")]
public virtual string ContentField { get; set; }
```

These blog posts refer to the `_content` computed index field from which the `Content` property is derived.

- http://andrewwburns.com/2015/09/03/appending-to-the-_content-field-in-sitecore-search-7-2-and-7-5/
- https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/66/sitecore_search_and_indexing_sc66-usletter.pdf
- http://sitecoregadgets.blogspot.co.uk/2009/11/working-with-lucene-search-index-in_25.html